# Cordova App Creating a directory

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am building a Cordova App by myself and i need to create a new folder to store images in phone's internal storage. I have visited a lot of articles online and everyone is giving the same solution but it is not working for me.

Following is the code i am using in OnDeviceReady event but it is not working.

```
var new_directory = 'TEST';
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
 fileSystem.root.getDirectory(new_directory, { create: true }, function (file) {
 alert("got the file: "+ file.name + ', ' + file.fullPath);
 });
}, function(error) {
 alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
});
```

For Debugging i have also tried to alert

> cordova.file

object but it is shown as undefined.
I have tried writing simple file request statement even its is not working

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, alert('success'), alert('failed'));
```

also the rest of the javascript code does not work when i write above code.

Please help me to get on with this.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to save the image files? In application folder or in Photo library?

Comment: I want to save file into a folder in root directory of internal storage. Is it possible that this issue is because i have android Nougot and it's not compatible with cordova-plugin-file

Answer (score 0):

Have you been asked to grant the proper **permissions** when you try to save the file? A window like this should have appeared:

[image]

If this is not the case, you are using an obsolete plugin version. Otherwise, there is something wrong with your code, sorry but I can't help you with that.